# Passing Nested Items to the Web Service Using Objective C iPhone App

Tags: ios

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a story object which consists of a genre object. And I need to pass a story object to a web service/ MVC action. The problem I am facing is that when I pass in the genre object it does not work. Even after converting the genre object to NSDictionary.

I have an objective-c class like the following:

```
@interface Story : NSObject 
{

}

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *storyId;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *abstract;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger userId;
@property (nonatomic,strong) Genre *genre;
```

Genre class is defined:

```
@interface Genre : NSObject
{

}

@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger genreId;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *title;
```

I am calling my ASP.NET action and passing the information like this:

```
[self POST:@"Stories/CreateStory" parameters:@{@"Title":story.title,@"Abstract":story.abstract
                                               ,@"UserId":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:story.userId],
                                               @"Genre":[story.genre toDictionary]

                                               } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

                                                   NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);


                                                   if(success) success(task,responseObject);



} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    if(failure) failure(task,error);

}];
```

The .NET action is defined like this:

```
 public JsonResult CreateStory(StoryViewModel storyViewModel)
```

StoryViewModel is define like this:

```
 public class StoryViewModel
    {
        public int StoryId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Abstract { get; set; }
        public bool IsFeatured { get; set; }
        public GenreViewModel Genre { get; set; }
    }
```

GenreViewModel is define:

```
public class GenreViewModel
    {
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
```

When I post I get some error that JSON is not formatted and fragments are not allowed. If I remove the Genre from the post and pass in GenreId then all works fine. What am I missing?

UPDATE: The exact error as follows:

```
(JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0xa1a7450 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

UPDATE: I have updated the code to pass in NSString json but still get the same error:

```
 NSData *genreData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[story.genre toDictionary] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:genreData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [self POST:@"Stories/CreateStory" parameters:@{@"Title":story.title,@"Abstract":story.abstract
                                                   ,@"UserId":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:story.userId],
                                                   @"Genre":json

                                                   } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

                                                       NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);


                                                       if(success) success(task,responseObject);



    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

        if(failure) failure(task,error);

    }];
```

Comment: I have explained in great detail of exactly what I want. If you have any questions I can surely clarify.

Comment: Try object keyvalue mapping library. It will help u convert ur object to json. Also help u to covert json to object model.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're converting genre to an NSDictionary.

What the Genre parameter needs to be is a String that represents a JSON dictionary instead such as:

```
{"GenreId":1, "Title":"MyGenre"}
```

^^ That is a JSON Dictonary but it's really just a string.

You can either create that JSON Dictionary yourself or do a conversion using a JSON Parser.

Comment: I have updated the code to pass genre as json string but still getting the same issue. Please see the original question with the updated code.

Comment: Ohhh. Your web service side is only accepting JSON, right? you're sending HTTP Parameters instead. You need to instead send with no parameters just with the body of the full JSON to be sent.

Comment: Yes web service takes in a model as shown in the original code. It maps each parameter of the request to the model itself. Sending it within the body will not work.

Comment: So is it accepting http parameters then or JSON on the server?

Comment: it takes in a model as shown in the original code. I believe it maps the form http parameters to the model.