# Nested Parameters AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

How can I POST nested parameters using AFNetworking? I am having trouble sending the genre object as the nested object of the story object. It should automatically map to the StoryViewModel's Genre property but it does not.

```
[self POST:@"Stories/CreateStory" parameters:@{@"Title":story.title,@"Abstract":story.abstract
                                                   ,@"UserId":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:story.userId],
                                                   @"Genre":[story.genre toDictionary] 


// The action is defined below: 

 public JsonResult CreateStory(StoryViewModel storyViewModel)

 public class StoryViewModel
    {
        public int StoryId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Abstract { get; set; }
        public bool IsFeatured { get; set; }
        public GenreViewModel Genre { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of showing us a server snippet (.NET?), why don't you show us 1) the HTTP request that was generated by your code and 2) the HTTP request you expected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Nested Items to the Web Service Using Objective C iPhone App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054443/passing-nested-items-to-the-web-service-using-objective-c-iphone-app)